# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, magento-1.7

This error show every..***.**please help me for the exact answer for this qyery**...

### **SQLSTATE[23000]**: **Integrity constraint violation: 1452**

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
    (`mydawai`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT
    `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
    (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE
     CA)

i'm importing the 20 to 50 thousand csv product they will show an error but if part into the 500 hundred -500 hundred list than some  of the product will be importing and someone showing error of **sql 23000. Integrity constraint violation: 1452 ?**

Comment: You tried to insert a record that'd be an orphan. there's nothing we can do to help you, since you haven't shown ANYTHING of what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the definition of the tables `cataloginventory_stock_item` and `catalog_product_entity`?

Comment: Please edit your question, try to improve the formatting, and ask an actual question.

Comment: u will do utf 8 format convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its means that there is a foreign key that is not satisfied (ie you need it to exist but it doesnt)

`catalog_product_entity` must have and entry for `entity_id` which is then referenced as `product_id` in `cataloginventory_stock_item`.
[image]

Comment: @AkhilJain it depends on what you are doing. if you are trying to insert a value you must have already inserted the corresponding entity

Comment: @burceyy sir.... i don't understand because i m new developer in magento....plz exact help for this error

Comment: @AkhilJain please provide the queries that are being run and then we can try and help

Comment: @sir bruceyyy when i importing the product .... then we show this error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 "my product list 20 to 50 thousand csv list but if i'm  import 500 hundred - hundred csv list is importing some of the csv will be importing and that someone show error ....

Comment: in that case it is because to import something into your `cataloginventory_stock_item` table with a `product_id` of XYZ, `catalog_product_entity` must contain a field with `entity_id == XYZ` before you import the csv. Basically somewhere in the csv there are fields whose product id numbers are not in you inventory catalog. Either add them before hand or remove those from the csv file

Comment: @sir cataloginventory_stock_item table in a product_id is same in the catalog_product_entity into entity_id.see the screenshort of mysql

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove any special chacarter in your Csv File. like ©, '', º
Thats works for me !

Comment: I opened my .csv in my text-editor and did a `find` with RegExpression search selected. This was my regex that led me straight to the invalid character(s): `[^a-zA-Z\d\s\.\-\/\+\(\)"'_,%&!]` Worked like a charm after that.

Comment: In my case I was  referencing at id which did not exist in the table being referenced